# XSS filter for grave accent

Tags: php, security, xss

for XSS protection in PHP I am using

```
htmlspecialchars($text,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
```

I read about how grave accents can be used as quotes. I am wondering is htmlspecialchars enough or should I also run a string replace for grave accents?

Comment: If you use `"` (double quotes) to open quotes, it must end with `"` too. As long as every `"` is handled you don't have to worry about XSS. The existance of any variant of quotes within `"..."` means no harm.

Comment: okay so their is no way someone can use grave accents to escape the escaped text?

Comment: Swap out `htmlspecialchars()` for `htmlentities()`

Answer (score 1):

Grave accents have no special meaning within HTML so are not an XSS attack vector there (unless you embed them in a context where they do have special meaning, but I can't think of any such contexts supported by HTML).

Comment: o_o https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#Grave_accent_obfuscation

Comment: @ScottArciszewski — Interesting. I wonder what browsers are vulnerable to that attack. Chrome, for instance, parses it correctly (and puts the backticks inside the attribute value) and refuses to execute JS in an image `src` anyway.

Comment: According to HTML5 spec, the only mention of grave quotes is that they are not allowed in an unquoted attribute: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attribute-value-(unquoted)-state

Comment: @ircmaxell, quentin - it's our old friend Internet Explorer that allows [attribute values to be quoted via backticks](https://html5sec.org/#102).

Comment: Ah, IE, the cause of and solution to... Wait, no. Just the cause of all of life's problems.